# ajax other parameter is null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

why my other paramter is null. "date" and "ids" is null while my "postedFile" and "amount" has a data. but when i try to removed "postedFile" parameter. the ids and date has a value. and it works fine. but i need the postedfile parameter

My Script

```
  var ids = [];
function add(id, isChecked) {
    if (isChecked) {
        ids.push(id);
    }
    else {
        var i = ids.indexOf(id);
        ids.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

function saveSelected() {
    //var shipmentId = $('#c-shipment-id').val();
    var date = $('#Date').val();
    var amount = $('#Amount').val();
    //var ImageFile = $('#imageUploadForm').val();

    $('#imageUploadForm').on("change", function () {
        var formdata = new FormData($('form').get(0));
        CallService(formdata);
    });

    function CallService(postedFile) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("index", "payment")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { ids: ids, amount: amount, date: date, postedFile: postedFile },
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            traditional: false,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int?[] ids, decimal? amount, DateTime? date, HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the codes are OK. Could you please try to debug (`F11` or `debugger;`) it, and check whether they have values before AJAX call or not?

Comment: Thanks for reply
when i try to alert the date it show the value. and when i click ok after alert the value is null

Comment: thanks the value of date it works but i have a problem in 'ids' becoz its part of datatable. how can i get all ids selected in datatable. ? thanks a lot

Comment: Does the *datatable* mean that a table which includes a checkbox column in the page? And you want the fetch all selected IDs?

Comment: yes the check box is column. yes i need to fetch all selected IDs.

Comment: please check my answer below. And please update your questions to add the secondary one.

Comment: hello thank you for helping me. prevously my code for getting ids is working but when i add the upload image using ajax the ids is null. see the reference below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments above, I guess you could try to pass all the values with parameters, instead of the variables, like: `CallService(formdata, ids, amount, date)`. It may works.

To answer your secondary question - ***Fetch all selected IDs in a table with a checkbox column***:

Fisrt, add the `ID` into the checkbox's ID in the view, e.g.:

```
foreach (var m in Model.Data)
{
    row++;
    <tr class="@(row % 2 == 0 ? "alter" : "")">
        <td class="first">
            <input id="chk_@m.ID" type="checkbox" onclick="js_selone(this)" />
        </td>
...
```

Then, Create a JS method `getSelVal()` to fetch all selected IDs and return an combined string with `,`, e.g.: *1,2,3*.

```
$.fn.getSelVal = function () {
    for (var e = "", t = $("input[type=checkbox]", this), n = 0; n < t.length; n++) t[n].checked && (e += "," + js_getid(t[n].id));
    return e.Trim(",");
}
```

Finally, you can call the method and pass the `ids` or `ids.toString().split(',')` to AJAX request:

```
ids = $('.table td').getSelVal().toString().split(',');
CallService(formdata, ids, amount, date)

function CallService(postedFile, ids, amount, date) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("index", "payment")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { ids: ids, amount: amount, date: date, postedFile: postedFile },
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            traditional: false,
            dataType:"json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
```